# Repository or documentation for gdisk error codes?

Tags: gdisk

I've thoroughly read through the gdisk man page and the author's walkthrough found here http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html

I'm wondering if there is a repository of error codes out there for gdisk. When I first started using gdisk I'd naturally make mistakes and see error codes:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: I
Problem opening I for reading! Error is 2.
The specified file does not exist!
```

Simple mistake right, I typed in something that doesn't exist.

Then the second mistake:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sda
Problem opening /dev/sda for reading! Error is 13.
You must run this program as root or use sudo!
```

This might be a silly question, but I'm curious if this is the 13th error what would the other 11 errors be that I haven't made a mistake for yet?

I did find one additional error code in an apple forum https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7584206

Here error code 1 seems to relate to gdisk encountering bios/mbr installations.

Comment: Thanks for linking that Apple discussions thread, it was useful in figuring out my problem (basically, you need to disable SIP in newer MacOS's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `gdisk` outputs “Error is ...”, the error is an [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) value. To see what they correspond to, run `errno -l` (at least on Linux systems).

Error 2 means “No such file or directory”, which makes sense because you presumably don’t have a file named `I`. Error 13 means “permission denied”, which suggests that you weren’t running `gdisk` as root (as indicated by the error message).